# XML расшифровка на русском

Tags: xml

Здравствуйте, сидел перебирал **XML** файлы на работе и задался вопросом, а почему же переводится именно **расширяемый язык разметки**? В то время как **extensible** в дословном переводе означает **растяжимый**, а **расширяемый** это: **extendable**; **expansible**?

Answer (score 1):

Сколько себя помню - Технические переводчики всегда переводили Extension как Расширение, а там в дело вступает словообразование.
И вот у нас уже вполне себе Extensible.